# Can a vacuum tube Triode increase the voltage in a circuit above the voltage rating of the batteries in the circuit?

Tags: vacuum-tube

I guess this will take a little explanation. I have not mastered the "sketching" used on this website yet. The triode in question has one plate circuit connected to a 90 volt battery and the filament voltage creating the space charge is 1.5 volts.  This tube is not using the third connection of the triode.

In essence the batteries are in series. In this simple connection is there any conceivable way that the total voltage can exceed the sum of the two batteries in the circuit. I believe the schematic I am viewing has a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: *I have not mastered the "sketching" used on this website yet* That's still no excuse for not including a schematic.

Comment: " any conceivable way that the total voltage can exceed the sum of the two batteries in the circuit" I would say no, unless it's part of a boost converter or voltage multiplier ..

Comment: The only thing a vacuum triode can do is modulate (i.e., _limit_) the flow of current through the device.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triode#Operation

Comment: Triodes do not create volts.

Comment: @Sedumjoy, between which two points do you suspect the schematic was wrong, and what was that voltage?  Is the filament of this triode attached to the cathode (or a directly heated cathode)?

Comment: thank you for response ...I believe the schematic gave an arbitrary example that does not fit the graph...I came to this conclusion after reading the wiki suggested by james large ( see comment about yours.)  sorry for all the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funnily enough, the total voltage range can slightly exceed the battery voltages.

Firstly the space charge is negative, so that unused third connection may float to a few volts negative with respect to the cathode.

In early battery operated vacuum tube circuits, this voltage (which tends to reduce the anode current) is controlled by providing a conducting path to ground with a "grid leak" resistance - usually in the megohm range, since grid current is in the microamp range.

Secondly, in an RF circuit, the load is often an inductor, either the primary of a transformer or an RF choke. Then the mean anode (plate) voltage is the battery voltage, but there is AC superimposed on that, so the peak voltage exceeds the battery voltage. This is essentially, as @pjc50 says, happens in a boost converter (which then rectifies those peaks).

Whether these apply to your schematic ... well, show us the schematic!

Comment: Last time I tried to explain how to view a  schematic where the lecture was I was scolded.  That being said you wouldn't happen to know  by how much a triode can increase the voltage would you?  Feel free to use my example.

Comment: Across the grid leak? maybe a volt max, if it's a 1.5V battery powered valve. If you're posting links for people to waste time following, the scolding is well deserved. Put the schematic image in the question.

Comment: not necessary ...you answered my concern very nicely ...thank you

Comment: A single-ended transformer-coupled class A audio amplifier is another example. The OTX primary inductance allows the plate voltage to swing way above the HT rail.

Comment: I guess we'll never know what the question really was, since there are so many missing parts to it, but @BrianDrummond when you say "total voltage" are you measuring from (open) grid to plate?  I can see that voltage being slightly above plate voltage (i.e., plate to cathode), but is that what he was asking?

Comment: maybe the schematic was right after all....according to EJP.  I will have to go back to the drawing board on this and brush up on my vacuum tubes.